# socket - read IP address from terminal

Tags: c, sockets, ip, inet

I'm reading addres from the terminal in this way to connect the client to a server, but I've been told that this is not correct because I should convert it through inet_pton function. Is this true? Can you explain me why?
I'm doing tests with 127.0.0.1 and everything seems to work fine with this code. The address is the first parameter after the name of the program...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct sockaddr_in Eaddr;
    Eaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    //other code to connect...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `inet_addr` is that it indicates errors returning `INADDR_NONE`, which coincides with the IP address 255.255.255.255. The `inet_pton` function has better error reporting: it returns 1 on success and 0 or -1 on error.

Answer (score 0):

From [inet_addr() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_addr.3.html)

```
   The inet_addr() function converts the Internet host address cp from
   IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte
   order.  If the input is invalid, INADDR_NONE (usually -1) is
   returned.  Use of this function is problematic because -1 is a valid
   address (255.255.255.255).  Avoid its use in favor of inet_aton(),
   inet_pton(3), or getaddrinfo(3), which provide a cleaner way to
   indicate error return.
```